# What is relation between the MyClass object and <T> in the given class 

Tags: c#, generics

What is relation between `MyClass` object and `<T>` in

```
public class MyClass<T> where T : myGeneric
{
}
```

**To Add to my question after  DBM's reply**

How is the implemention above is better than

```
IGenericInterface
{
 int Bar();
}

public abstract GenericClass : IGenericInterface   
{
    public virtual int Bar()
    {
     return 1; 
    }

}
```

and then using the abstraft class to implement

```
public class MyClass  : GenericClass 
{
   IGenericInterface GenericObject ;
}
```

Comment: You can't have an abstract method with implementation.

Comment: Thanks , I corrected it now , Thing is i can have an Abstract class and havae many implelemtation of IGenericInterface and i can set MyClassobject.GenericObject at run time , then why do i need Generics ? Does it reduces the code size or am i missing something ?

Comment: Well, with the constraint you provided, it's not particularly useful. But look at generic collections (such as List<T>) for what I consider to be the easiest-to-grasp example of generics. You provide the class with a type that it will be operating on throughout its lifecycle at construction.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to read up on C# [generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). The code you posted is a class called `MyClass` that can take anything that derives from the class `myGeneric`. The `T` is a placeholder for the type.

You could, for example, do

```
public class myGeneric
{
      public int Bar() 
      {
           return 1;
      }
}

public class MyClass<T> where T : myGeneric 
{ 
      public void DoSomething(T foo) 
      {
           int x = foo.Bar();
      }
}
```

So in the example above, `x` would be 1.

Comment: But i can achieve the same thing keeping an instance of myGeneric in MyClass .

Answer (score 0):

"MyClass" is the class name, "<T>" is the generic parameter list.

Answer (score 0):

1. Does not require you to cast MyClass to IGenericInterface
2. At compile time, all occurrences of T will be replaced with the actual class type that was used in the call, rather than the class being casted at runtime to the IGenericInterface.

Comment: i think you got my question, Let me contemplate

Comment: Are you sure of #2 , i want to assign objects at runtime. its somethig like foreach(Myclass obj in List<Myclass>){ obj.Genericobject = factory.Getobjectusingconfiguration() ;  }